# Visual Studio 2015, SQL Server

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2015

This is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("data source=.; databases=manager; integrated security =SSPI");

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM PRODUCTLINE",con);
        con.Open();

        SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        GridView1.DataSource = rdr;
        GridView1.DataBind();

        con.Close();
    }
}
```

which causes an error:

> Compiler Error Message: CS0103: The name 'GridView1' does not exist in the current context

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: drag and drop gridview control to your design view

Comment: Are you sure you have your `GridView1` on your `aspx` file? 
or as @Damith said on the DesignView.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add GridView1 to _Default page, you can drag and drop GridView control to your page or define your gridview on aspx page like below

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="true"></asp:GridView>
```