# MS Visual Studio "Error CS0103 The name 'GridView1' does not exist in the current context"

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, web

I have an old Web App (ASP.NET Web forms) developed in VS 2015 and it runs fine under that version (see details here).
Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2015
Version 14.0.25420.01 Update 3

When I open it with VS 2019 (version details below) I get the above error but it runs fine when I start it up.
Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019
Version 16.11.5

Have been searching around but no luck - very perplexing - any ideas please ?

Comment: This maybe would help you.[GridView1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40821831/16764901)

Comment: Thanks Jiale for your suggestion but after reading it ... I checked again and the gridview definition is in the Default.aspx file and is visible in design view and the source code view shows it is there and of course it is referenced in the Default.aspx.cs file also.
As I said in the append - "I have an old Web App (ASP.NET Web forms) developed in VS 2015 and it runs fine under that version "
The problem surfaced when i tried to run it under VS 2019.

Comment: It may be a problem caused by the migration, you can check in this regard.